# Updating table based on date field without using loops with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, datetime

I have the following script I created to update a schedule table in Microsoft SQL Server. The primary key field is a date time and are individual dates on the calendar. The Employees are scheduled for 7 consecutive days and I need to alternate between 2 employees for seven days at a time going from each Monday through Sunday to the end of the year. I created the following script using loops and am looking for a way to accomplish it without using loops. Thanks!

```
DECLARE @z_start INT
DECLARE @z_date DATETIME

SET @z_date = '03/07/16'

WHILE(@z_date < '12/31/16')
BEGIN
    SET @z_start = 0

    WHILE(@z_start < 7) BEGIN
        UPDATE EmployeeOnCall
        SET employeeName = 'Jones, Jim'
        WHERE deptID = 25 AND weekDay = @z_date

        SET @z_date = DATEADD(dd, 1, @z_date)
        SET @z_start = @z_start + 1
    END

    SET @z_start = 0

    WHILE(@z_start < 7) BEGIN
        UPDATE EmployeeOnCall
        SET employeeName = 'Penton, Andy'
        WHERE deptID = 25 AND weekDay = @z_date

        SET @z_date = DATEADD(dd, 1, @z_date)
        SET @z_start = @z_start + 1
    END
END;
```

Comment: You could use a numbers or tally for this quite easily. I would also urge you to use the ANSI format for date strings. 'YYYYMMDD' The way you have your date strings will fail if the dateformat or localization is not the same as yours. Here is a great link to a tally table. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: You earn a big, fat +1 for *looking for a way to accomplish it without using loops* ! (I have no time to script this out at the moment, but I'll come back later (but probably its answered then...)

Comment: I am a little confused here. Your second loop is overwriting the data you updated in the first loop.

Comment: Do you only need to do this for two employees?

Comment: I need to this for only 2 employees yes.
So starting on Monday 03/07/16 through Sunday 03/13/16 I would need to schedule Jim. And starting on Monday 03/08/16 through Sunday 03/14/16 schedule Andy, repeating that pattern through the end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `DATEPART` and a CTE.  Here's the relevant part:

```
;with wkNum as (
    SELECT weekDay, EmployeeName, deptID, (DATEPART(wk, weekDay) / 2) % 2 as period 
    FROM EmployeeOnCall
)
UPDATE wkNum
SET employeename = CASE WHEN wkNum.period = 0 THEN 'Jones, Jim' ELSE 'Penton, Andy' END
```

The idea is to determine what week of the year it is, divide that by 2, and then modulo it by the number of employees you're dealing with. 
And here's a test script:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (weekDay datetime, employeename varchar(50), deptID int);

DEClARE @startdate datetime = '2016-02-16';
declare @enddate datetime = '2016-12-31';

;with 
 N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 t1, N0 t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 t1, N1 t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 t1, N2 t2)
,N4 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N3 t1, N3 t2)
,N5 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N4 t1, N4 t2)
,N6 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N5 t1, N5 t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N6)
INSERT @test (weekDay, deptID)
SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate) as thedate, 25
FROM nums
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate) + 1


;with wkNum as (
SELECT weekDay, EmployeeName, deptID, (DATEPART(wk, weekDay) / 2) % 2 as period FROM @test
)
UPDATE wkNum
SET employeename = CASE WHEN wkNum.period = 0 THEN 'Jones, Jim' ELSE 'Penton, Andy' END

SELECT * FROM @test
```

If you have a table of employees to pull from it might be expanded like so:

```
DECLARE @emps TABLE (Name varchar(100));

INSERT @emps VALUES ('Dan'), ('Joe'), ('Asdf')

UPDATE eoc
SET employeename = emp.Name
FROM EmployeeOnCall eoc
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) rn, Name FROM @emps) emp
ON ((DATEPART(wk, weekDay) / 2) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @emps)) + 1 = emp.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

The **best** approach is to populated persisted `Calendar` table. Fill it with list of days that covers for the start 10 years, mark each day as workday or weekend day, append any columns you need. And simply join it, filter by edge dates you got.

Your case does not demonstrate why you mentioned 7-days intervals. 7 days means every day. Let's say you have `@startdate` and `@enddata` variables. Let's generate date list and join it with destination table.

```
declare
  @startdate  datetime = '20150612',
  @enddate    datetime = '20160122',
  @period_len int

set @period_len = datediff(dd, @startdate, @enddate)

;with cteCounter as
(
  select top (@period_len)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.object_id) as counter
  from sys.columns c
  cross join sys.columns cc
  order by counter
),
cteCalendar as
(
  select c.counter, dateadd(dd, c.counter-1, @startdate) as calendar_date
  from cteCalendar c
  order by calendar_date
)
UPDATE e SET
  employeeName = 'Jones, Jim'
FROM EmployeeOnCall e
inner join cteCalendar c on c.calendar_date = e.weekDay
WHERE e.deptID = 25
```